# "consumed by something"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is meant by **"consumed"** and **"consumed by"**  apart from the general meaning?

For example : in the movie *Civil War* T'Challa says to Zemo

> Vengeance has **consumed** you. It's **consuming** them. I'm done letting it **consume** me."

What does he actually mean by it ?

Comment: Relatively speaking, ***consume*** is a "50-cent word". But the slightly more "slangy" expression [***eaten up** with jealousy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eaten+up+with+jealousy%22) is commonplace. It's a trivial metaphoric usage implying that you've been ***completely overcome*** by [jealousy, rage, etc.].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best definition of the idiom to be consumed by something, in this context, is **to be completely absorbed and controlled by one's passion or lust for something or someone.**

It is most often used to describe a very strong emotional state, for example, consumed by love, consumed by jealousy, consumed by hatred, etc, the point being that this emotion has completely taken over at the expense of everything else.

Comment: so, what i can understand is , if one is consumed by something ,one is overwhelm with it . He thinks of nothing else but revenge?

Comment: also, please let me know if the above sentence has any grammatical errors thanks

Comment: I would say that 'overwhelmed' has a slightly different meaning to 'consumed' in this case. If you are 'consumed' by something, such as revenge, then yes, it's all you can think of, at the expense of everything else. But to be overwhelmed by something, for example, grief, means the the grief is too much for you to bear.

Answer (score 2):

When *something* "consumes" you, it spreads over you and can engulf you (figuratively), like a piece of food

> A nagging fear ate away at her, slowly consuming her confidence.

[image]

If the *something* completely takes over one's life it can become an obsession and

> all consuming
>
> Painting was an *all consuming* passion for him, he had not eaten in days.

Your passage is saying that thoughts of revenge began to take over the thoughts and lives of the characters.